# Is there any way to unbind the reference between two objects

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I have the following C# code.

```
    SomeObject myObject = new SomeObject();
    SomeObject anotherObject = new SomeObject();
    anotherObject = myObject;
```

If I modify myObject, anotherObject gets modified.
Is there any way to unbind them?
Something like:

```
Object.unbind(myObject, anotherObject);
```

So that modifying myObject would not affect anotherObject?

Comment: no, but you might want to use some cloning or copying mechanism, there are a lot of them in c#

Comment: Why would you even do that to begin with?

Comment: @IanKemp Long confusing code, Object.ReferenceEquals(myObject, anotherObject) returns true. Not sure how that happened. Need to modify myObject without changing anotherObject.

Comment: What happened is that you abandoned the second instance and pointed the second *variable* to the *instance* referenced by the first variable.

Comment: `anotherObject` is __not__ an object, it is a reference to an object. After the first assignment (initialization) it points to a different object than `myObject`. After the second assignment, both `myObject` and `anotherObject` point to the same object. Consider: rename `myObject` to `refToMyObject` and `anotherObject` to `refToASomeObject`. Is it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might know ***class*** is ***CallByReference*** and anything you do on second object will reflect on first object and vice versa. So clone it, or Just create an empty Second object and set the properties one by one.

Comment: I think this might be the best/only solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the variable to a different object, or to null:

```
anotherObject = new SomeObject();
```

or

```
anotherObject = null;
```